# JSF 2 : tag wrapper to encapsulate common attribute values?

Tags: java, jsf-2, facelets

Based on this previous question [How to get ID of calling component in the getter method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469992/how-to-get-id-of-calling-component-in-the-getter-method) , here's another idea i want to ask your opinion about :

there are lots of duplicated code across jsf pages such as these examples (notice the repeating size and maxlength attribute) across components :

```
<h:inputText label="#{msgs.userId}" id="UserId" value="#{userBean.userId}" 
   required="true" 
   size="#{variableConfigBean.getSize(component.id)}" 
   maxlength="#{variableConfigBean.getMaxLength(component.id)}"
/>
<h:inputSecret label="#{msgs.password}" id="Password" value="#{userBean.password}" 
   required="true"  
   size="#{variableConfigBean.getSize(component.id)}" 
   maxlength="#{variableConfigBean.getMaxLength(component.id)}"
/>
```

Im thinking of :

1. using composite component for that
   input text tag,
2. hardcoding the size and maxlength in the implementation section of that composite component,
3. so that i dont have to duplicate all
   these stuffs everytime i need to use
   that component.
4. but i'll have to open
   up all attributes in the interface
   section of that composite component

Is this idea ok, or perhaps there are other better ways to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so. I've also implemented it in some projects. It only adds some (minor) overhead. You could for this particular purpose also just use a Facelets tag file instead of a JSF composite component. It's not mandatory to define the attributes then. In your particular case you can refactor pretty much duplicates if you reuse the bean property name as id and key for message bundle label.

E.g.

```
<my:input type="text" bean="#{userBean}" property="userId" required="true" />
<my:input type="secret" bean="#{userBean}" property="password" required="true" />
```

with the following in a Facelets tag file:

```
<c:set var="id" value="#{not empty id ? id : property}" />
<c:set var="required" value="#{not empty required and required}" />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{type == 'text'}">
        <h:inputText id="#{id}" 
            label="#{msgs[property]}"
            value="#{bean[property]}" 
            size="#{config.size(id)}" 
            maxlength="#{config.maxlength(id)}" 
            required="#{required}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="#{type == 'secret'}">
        <h:inputSecret id="#{id}" 
            label="#{msgs[property]}"
            value="#{bean[property]}" 
            size="#{config.size(id)}" 
            maxlength="#{config.maxlength(id)}" 
            required="#{required}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h:outputText value="Unknown input type: #{type}" />
    </c:otherwise>            
</c:choose>
```

I've however implemented it with an `<h:outputLabel>` before and a `<h:message>` after which makes refactoring like this more reasonable.

Comment: I've however implemented it with an <h:outputLabel> before and a <h:message> after which makes refactoring like this more reasonable. <-- Im sorry that i dont understand this message, could you please clarify, im curious :) .. Thank you so much for the solution, gonna refresh the custom facelet tag solution 1st before trying it. But if i remember correctly, i wont be able to attach listeners, validators, etc for the custom tags. Have this been ever an issue for you ? And it'll be my first time using jstl in my jsf page, hehehe .. Thank you !

Comment: A `<h:outputLabel for="#{id}" value="#{msgs[property]}"/>` before the `<c:choose>` and a `<h:message for="#{id}"/>` there after. As to the listeners/validators, I am not sure, but it sounds like you just need `<ui:insert/>` in tag's body. I however don't discourage use of composite component by the way. In my experience, they had in my particular case the disadvantage that they ends up as a single component. My intent was to have a 3-column `<h:panelGrid>` with all fields and it only worked with a tag file since it actually returned 3 components (label, input, message) instead of only one.

Comment: Oh i see, you were thinking of a composite component returning 3 components. nice :) Okay, im trying your suggestions now. wish me luck. Thanks again..