# How to update specific row in Primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces 3.5, Mojarra 2.1.14. This is my PF datatable, it contains one non-editable boolean column named 'automatic', and editable 'label' column:

```xml
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.contents}" paginator="true" var="row" 
  editable="true" editMode="cell" rows="25" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50" id="list">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="header1" /></f:facet>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.automatic}" disabled="true" id="isAutomatic"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="header2" /></f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.label}"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{row.label}"></p:inputText>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.onEditLabel}" update="isAutomatic"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Cell edit event listener:

```java
public void onEditLabel(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        DataTable s = (DataTable) event.getSource();
        MyEntity d = (MyEntity) s.getRowData();
        try {
            d.setAutomatic(false);
            myDAO.save(d);
            addMessage("Change saved!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            addErrorMessage("Label could not be saved!");
            getFacesContext().validationFailed();
        }
    }
}
```

The cell editor works, sends data to listener, and it is correctly persisted to the database. The 'automatic' flag is also cleared by cell edit event listener, and gets correctly persisted to the database. The problem is that 'automatic' checkbox is not updated on the client.

I also tried

```xml
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.onEditLabel}" update="list"/>
```

which correctly updated the checkbox, but also causes focus to be lost, and wastes bandwidth.

How can I update just a specific cell after cellEdit event is fired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `p:ajax` tag is inside `p:dataTable` no in some specific row or column, so you cent so easy update some relative component id. You can with help of `RequestContext` update specific component in cell. So, remove `update` from `p:ajax` and add this to your `onEditLabel` method:

```java
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(
  s.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) +
  ":" + event.getRowIndex() +
  ":isAutomatic"
);
```

As you can see, id of component inside cell has row number before id you assigned.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but definitely is not the best practice. First, I am relying on particular component id naming convention. Second, my controller bean now contains frontend logic (view IDs). Best solution would be to add such a feature to PF DataTable. Sigh. :)

Comment: I don't completely agree with you. Backing bean is tightly coupled with presentation layer (as for example your from AJAX listener call backing bean method). It would be bad if you put business logic in backing bean. I agree that putting id in backing bean is not very nice, but in this moment I don't see any easy solution.

Comment: I agree there is no easy solution, this will have to do. Thanks again!

Comment: Its not working for me can u please tell what can be the problem

Comment: FYI RequestContext has been replaced by PrimeFaces class since PF 7.0 as detailed in the migration guide https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can solve this without having to know the details of the ID of the component you wish to update. You can pass it as a parameter to the bean.

First, bind the component you wish to update. You don't actual need a bean to which this component is bound to. You just need to define some value which you can use to identify this component later in your JSF.  So in your case, you would do something like:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{isAutomaticComponent}" value="#{row.automatic}" disabled="true" id="isAutomatic"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Now access the component when you do your update. ie:

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.onEditLabel(isAutomaticComponent.clientId)}" />
```

Now you can update the component from your cellEdit event method without knowing the contents of the ID. ie:

```
public void onEditLabel(CellEditEvent event, String idOfComponentToUpdate) {
...
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(idOfComponentToUpdate);
...
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I wonder if component binding would work correctly inside a datatable. Also I believe you could use something like #{component.clientId}, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469992/how-to-get-id-of-calling-component-in-the-getter-method

Comment: My situation is a little bit different, so I have not tried exactly this scenario, but I have done something very similar. I believe it would work for the scenario posted here. And yes. Component binding does work inside a datatable. That is closer to my scenario actually as I wanted to update the ID of a button within a row of a table, but had trouble doing it since the rows in the table are dynamic and thus so was the ID of the button. Passing the ID of the component in this fashion was the best solution I could find.