# How to add a row to h:dataTable dynamically without rerendering the whole table?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I want to add a row to a `<h:dataTable>` dynamically, but I don't want to rerender the whole datatable, because the user could have some of the rows expanded etc., which would be closed after the AJAX call.

Is it possible to do this in JSF?

Comment: Which component, library are you using? Can you post come code? Regards,

Comment: i just use h:dataTable

Comment: Checkout here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257554/how-to-update-specific-row-in-primefaces-datatable Although it is related to Primefaces datatable but it can be useful in your case also

Comment: hm there thy just update a already existing row, but i need a new one, thanks

Comment: Unless I've misread your question @wutzebaer, you can't update what's not there. The datatable is a container, and the datatable needs to be aware of a new child row before the changes to it's content can be reflected. The way ajax-updates work, a child component cannot be effectively updated without the knowledge of the enclosing parent, especially if the child wasn't there in the initial render to begin with

Comment: hm ok and what about another container? i'm trying at the moment to rerender a h:panelGroup, add a sub-panelgroup and nextime rerendering this sub panel group, and so on

Comment: @wutzebaer post a real question, with code. I can't get much from "and so on"