# How to update specific row in dataTable with the updated information from backing bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I need your assistance in updating only a specific row values in a dataTable not the whole dataTable having particular values once the user click on the "Update" commandButton.

The dataTable looks like:

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{testController.employeeList}" id="Employee" var="emp" 
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
    selection="#{testController.selectedEmployees}" rowKey="#{emp.id}" 
rowSelectMode="checkbox">
                        <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column/>
                            <p:column headerText="ID"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Name"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Remarks"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Update"/>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" id="name"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remarks">
                        <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Update">
                        <p:commandButton id="updateCmd" title="Update"
                                         actionListener="#{testController.updateRecord}">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And here is the method code:

```
public void updateRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Employee selectedRecord = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{emp}", Employee.class);
    selectedRecord.setRemarks("Updated");
    String name1=selectedRecord.getRemarks();
    System.out.println("name1"+name1);
        // I need to update the row only or the cell with the remarks Updated by
 //without refreshing full dataTable
    //RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("request:Employee"); 
//Above line will update the full table, I need only the row or the cell value
    }
```

Comment: is this a duiplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120998/update-single-row-from-datatable-jsf-ajax

Comment: @Kukeltje it doesn't show the answer

Comment: In your xhtml page, I can see there is only one input field remarks. But in your update method you are updating the name. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Unknown I have modified the code and I want to update the remarks for that row or cell only "to refresh".

Comment: @Unknown Thanks for the solution ... I will try it by tomorrow and I will keep you updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can use `update` attribute of commandButton to update the components with ajax

From Primefaces documentation the description for `update` attribute is

> Component(s) to be updated with ajax.

So you can update your specific column by the components id.

```
<p:dataTable>
...
<p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" id="name" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Remarks">
     <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}"/>
</p:column>
<p:commandButton id="updateCmd" title="Update" update="name inputT1" partialSubmit="true"   actionListener="#{testController.updateRecord}">
</p:commandButton>
</p:dataTable>
```

2) If you want to update the particular column using Java then you need to pass the rowId to the Controller.

```
<h:form id="myform">
        <p:dataTable value="#{testController.employeeList}" id="Employee"
                    var="emp" widgetVar="employeeTable" rowIndexVar="row"
                    filteredValue="#{testController.filteredEmployees}"
                    rowKey="#{emp.id}">
                    <p:column headerText="Id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" id="name" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remarks">
                        <p:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Update" >

                    <p:commandButton id="updateCmd" title="Update" partialSubmit="true"
                                     actionListener="#{testController.updateRecord}">
                            <f:attribute name="rowId" value="#{row}" />
                     </p:commandButton>
                     </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
```

ActionListner method:

```
public void updateRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Integer rowId = (Integer)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("rowId");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Employee selectedRecord = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{emp}", Employee.class);
        selectedRecord.setRemarks("Updated");
        String name1=selectedRecord.getRemarks();
        System.out.println("name1"+name1);
      RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myform:Employee:"+rowId+":inputT1"); 
        }
```