# How to avoid reload entire table while deleting a single row in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using a web application with Prime Faces.

In my datatable, in which a column is an image, I've the pagination. So I never load too many rows.

For each row I've the button "delete row". Here the code

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableUploadedImages" var="singleRow">
    ...
    ...
    <p:column headerText="#{msg['azioni']}" width="70">
        <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" 
                             title="delete Row" 
                             ajax="true"
                             action="#{myController.deleteRow(singleRow.id)}"
                             update="dataTableUploadedImages">
            </p:commandButton>
        </div>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

After clicking over the button, the application refresh the entire table instead of simply remove the single row.
In this page, refreshing all the rows is expensive (because a column contains an image) and slow down the application.

**Is it possible to remove a row without reloading the entire table?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update specific row in dataTable with the updated information from backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208386/how-to-update-specific-row-in-datatable-with-the-updated-information-from-backin)

Comment: Not a duplicate question. We're speaking about deletion. Not update

Comment: Then the easiest way would be to do it by client side and not use the `update` attribute at all.

Comment: Is there some example? Some article to read?

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170997/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-a-table-row-with-jquery

Comment: And this could easily be added as a 'deleteRow' on the widget... Will implement this the coming day and file a pull request with PrimeFaces