# Update row from PrimeFaces dataTable by data-rk attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

There is any way to update a tr tag by data-rk attribute, ¿using update(primefaces) attribute?

```
<tr data-ri="0" data-rk="1">
...
</tr>
```

ty.

Comment: Check PrimeFaces selectors...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do PrimeFaces Selectors as in update="@(.myClass)" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257554/how-to-update-specific-row-in-primefaces-datatable

Comment: thank you guys, I'll check!